# getText.toString() cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I have a TextView which is properly displaying the facebook id.

When I try to get the text from it for an http request I get  ***Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject***. Example:

```
fbID = fbidTextView.getText().toString();
```

If I manually assign a value to fbID, the request works with no errors. Example:

```
fbID = "12345678910112";
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with what I'm doing in the first code snippet?

I have tried a lot of things and I'm stumped.

Thanks for your time!

**Edit** Added CheckUser AsyncTask

Sorry, missed this bit:

```
        new CheckUser().execute(fbID);



class CheckUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    /**
     * Checking if user has a username yet
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        //String fbid = fbID;
        String fbid = args[0];

        Log.d("Arg fb: ", fbid);

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbid", fbid));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_user, "POST", params);
```

**EDIT AGAIN, Custom JSON Parser class:**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/JSON Parser(23462): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value You of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 23462
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at com.example.androidhive.MainActivity$CheckUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:209)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at com.example.androidhive.MainActivity$CheckUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-02 22:58:42.953: E/AndroidRuntime(23462):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
```

MainActivity Line 209 is this:

```
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

For some reason when I use **fbidTextView.getText().toString();** json becomes null?

Comment: fbID is JSONObject instance ?

Comment: Are you getting the String value from TextView? How are you converting it to JSONObject?

Comment: Can you post your request code?

Comment: I add fbID as an argument in my AsyncTask. I'll post some relevant code to clarify.

Comment: @user3689720 Better to use utf-8 for both charset(in inputstream and paramstring)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to asign String (fbid) into JSON Object

```
String id = fbidTextView.getText().toString();

JSONObject json=new JSONObject("{\"fbID\":"+ id +"}");
```

Comment: Are you using custom JSONParser class. Can you post here. Thanks

Comment: This is definitely the code from the tutorial I used, but I'm still confused. Since my code works if I just use fbID = "12345678910112"; doesn't that mean that the issue is not with the JSONParser itself, but with the code that tries to get fbID from the TextView?

Comment: Your passing List<NameValuePair> params on makeHttpRequest(url_check_user, "POST", params) but the method which receive has makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        JSONObject params) argument. Does it will work ? Argument itself mismatching.

Comment: Ahh Sorry!! That was only mismatching because I tried Sripathi's solution and it changed. I've now posted my current (and original) JSONParser class.

Comment: Ok Now tell me on which line your getting error ?. Can you post logcat error

Comment: Posted logcat. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It will be helpful if you post MainActivity.java also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem,

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbid", fbid));

    // getting JSON Object
    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_user, "POST", params);
```

you used the param as list. But it should be JsonObject.
Use this one,

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put(("fbid", fbid);
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_user, "POST", params);
```

Comment: Yes sure.. Why you are doubting? Is there any flaw?

Comment: Passing parameter  List<NameValuePair> is correct. The issue may be something else.

Comment: When trying this method it causes me to have to change 'String, String, <List NameValuePair> to String, String JSONObject, which causes errors in the custom JSONParser class. The first error is "The constructor UrlEncodedFormEntity(JSONObject) is undefined".

Comment: @Ramesh_D Yep I din't noticed about that, you are right. Thanks for alerting me..

Comment: @user3689720 Sorry I din't noticed your JsonParser class. You were right, I will update my answer soon and come back to you..

Comment: @user3689720 There should be a clash between utf-8 and iso-8859-1. Change the encoding to the similar one and check.

Comment: @user3689720 Better to use utf-8 for both charset(in inputstream and paramstring)